# Alternativa a `this.setState(value, ()=>{})` con React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

como puedo hacer que espere cambiar estado para continuar la siguiente línea de código?

tengo `useState` pero no hay forma de esperar a que actulize antes de continuar, con `React Clases` si habia, como este `this.setState(value, ()=>{})`  donde habi un `callback` al finalizar.

he intentado uno similar

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const UseStateCallback = (initialState) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const resolverRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (resolverRef.current) {
      resolverRef.current(state);
      resolverRef.current = null;
    }
  }, [resolverRef.current, state]);

  const handleSetState = useCallback(
    (stateAction) => {
      setState(stateAction);
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolverRef.current = resolve;
      });
    },
    [setState]
  );

  return [state, handleSetState];
};
export default UseStateCallback;
```

funciona en una primera instancia pero no vuelve a funcionar mas, es decir que lo he puesto en un validador de formalario, la primera me captura las validadciones, pero despues no vuelve a entrar mas al `callbak` que he definido

```
  const [error, seterror] = UseStateCallback(false);


  const onSubmit = () => {
    seterror(true, () => {
      if (ErrorTags()) {
        AlertError({
          addToast,
          message: 'llene todos los datos'
        });
        return false;
      }
      setIsLoading(true);
      login({ ...credentials});
    });
  };
```

es aquí donde el `submit()` solo se ejecuta una vez y vuelve a enviar, como puedo solucionarlo, otra forma de hacer que espere cambiar estado para continuar?

Comment: Esto no esta claro `funciona en una primera instancia pero no vuelve a funcionar mas`, hay que desarrollar un poco mas la pregunta. Saludos